# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2

Tags: json, gson, illegalstateexception

Hi i need to find out value of one key(i.e `type`) in the Json before parsing it to actual Java object, but i doing so leads to following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2
```

**Json**

```
{
    "type":1,
    "password":"ac@123",
    "role":"normaluser",
    "name":"Archana Chatterjee",
    "username":"a.chatterjee",
    "designation":"Teacher",
    "id":"T_02",
    "age":42
}
```

**Code**

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Pair>>() {}.getType();
ArrayList<Pair> list = gson.fromJson(json, listType);
```

**Class**

```
class Pair {
    String property;
    Object value;
    // has getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Your Json is not an array is an object.

Comment: but i tried it with `TypeToken<Pair>()`also, it returns a empty `Pair` object, i.e, `property ` and `value` has `null` value

Comment: You  need learn about Json serialize/deserialize works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After reading [this](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Collection-with-Objects-of-Arbitrary-Types), i found a better approach of solving my problem. Here i need a low-level streaming parser to get the `JsonObject`.

```
        String json3 = "{\"type\":1,\"password\":\"ac@123\",\"role\":\"normaluser\",\"name\":\"Archana Chatterjee\",\"username\":\"a.chatterjee\",\"designation\":\"Teacher\",\"id\":\"T_02\",\"age\":42}";
        JsonParser jParser = new JsonParser();
        JsonObject jObject = (JsonObject) jParser.parse(json3);
```

Now `JsonObject` has capability of returning the value of a key. [javadoc for same](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html)

```
        JsonElement elem = jObject.get("type");
```

`JsoElement's` toString() returns the value of the key. (i.e value of type here)

```
        System.out.println(elem);
```

**Output**

```
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I suggest you to take a look at [**Gson docs**](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) and [**JSON specs**](http://www.json.org/) because it looks like you're rather lost...

With Gson, the normal and the easiest way to parse your JSON is creating a structure of Java classes that *matches* the structure of your JSON.

In this case, your JSON is an object (it's surrounded by `{ }`) and contains a number of properties (i.e., `type`, `password`, `role`, etc.).

So, what you need is to create a Java class with those properties (matching the names):

```
class User
  String type
  String password
  String role
  // ...
```

Then you just need to call Gson, give it some JSON string and tell it in which class you want that JSON to be parsed into:

```
User someUser = gson.fromJson( yourJson, User.class );
```

---

***EDIT***: If your JSON may change, you cannot use a single class to parse it, so you have a couple of options. Probably the easiest one is to try to parse your JSON into a `Map` structure.

A `Map` is an object (like your JSON is) that contains *pairs* `Key=>Value` (e.g., `'type'=>1`). So you can try to parse it likt this:

```
Type mapType = new TypeToken< Map<String, String> >() {}.getType();
HashMap<String, String> map = gson.fromJson( yourJson, mapType );
```

Note: the problem with this approach is that, as Java is a strongly-typed language, your JSON has to have pairs of the same type (e.g., ). In this case, your fields `'type'` and `'age'` are not strings, but integers, but I'm pretty sure it can automatically convert them into strings...

If it can't, or if it's really important to parse `'type'` and `'age'` into integers, your only option is to write a [**Custom Deserializer**](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Writing-a-Deserializer)...

Comment: Actually i can receive 3 types of Json, so which json belongs to which class depends on `type` parameter. Like if type is 1 then i should use A.class, if type is 2 then B.class. That is why i said i need to get `type` value before parsing to actual data-structure.